# Why CNiButton cannot be changed from thread except main thread?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, labview, led

I have 2 applications in fact two of them is the same application but they work on two different computers and the first computer (let say A) controls the second computer (let say B) remotely to control hardwares that are connected to the B. The B can also controls all hardware alone.

The problem is that the CNiButton button in the software cannot be turned on if the A say to B as turn on, but when the only B is running , it can trigger/turn on the CNiButton. So I assume it's not a library issue. Because it works normally only when the B try to turn on, however, the A tells B to turn on, it does not work/turn on. In addition, the software in the B is terminate abnormally.

I can't share code because code is not accessible. Anyway I really need your different opinions according to

1. The A computer can turn on CNiButton on own software that run on it,
2. The B computer can turn on CNiButton on own software that run on it,

A and B computer with together so B has always listen to the A computer if there is packet from A, B do action according to packet

3. The B can not turn on the CNiButton if A send a packet including turn on CNiButton and program terminate.

What could be the reason for these?
What can cause the program to terminate?

I also give some informations about my systems
 - There are many thread to listens hardwares
 - B including thread to listen A
 - B call button1 events if A push on button1 by communicating RS432

I think the threads overlap each other, but I don't understand why this is happening for CNiButton that doesn't happen for other standard buttons.

Also Can there be any reason why this button should not run from another thread except for main thread?

In the meantime, the program works for VisualC ++ 6.0 and has suitable drivers for NI hardware.

Edit1

I think need to add some code that I remembered!

There is a button

```
CNiButton ledTemperature;
```

This button look like a LabView led if you know the LabView. And One thread listen to the B computer let say void listenBComputer() method and the method of the MFC CMSComm class,

```
 CMSComm comPort;
 void MyClass:: listenBComputer();
```

listenBComputer() method call the B comuter and if B click for example: fireOpenButton then A do the same thing and call the method of fireOpenButton pretending like A computer click the fireOpenButton and must be turn on the "ledTemperature" CNiButton like,

```
ledTemperature.SetValue(true) ;
```

This operation does not work and throw exception when B computer send a command to A but the same code and process or whatever we say is working if A click fireOpenButton without B computer.